# Async Task method is not running in parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a class with below two methods

```
public static async Task UploadReportData()
{

    List<string> input = new List<string>();

    input = getdatafromdb();

    int counter = 1;
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();


    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        tasks.Add(uploadtoTable(item)); //for each input it waits here until uploadtoTable method is completed. 

        if (counter % 3 == 0)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            tasks.Clear();
        }

        counter++;
    }

}

public static async Task uploadtoTable(string item)
{
    failureTableModels = //some database calls
    successTableModels = //some database calls
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    if (failureTableModels.Count > 0)
        tasks.Add(BulkUpsertDetailedReport(failureTableModels));
    if (successTableModels.Count > 0)
        tasks.Add(BulkUpsertDetailedReport(successTableModels));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

the "uploadtoTable" method is not getting called in parallel. I would expect it to run in 3 threads. What am I missing here ?

Comment: If you use await it works like sync

Comment: @MoinulIslam You mean the `await` present in `uploadtoTable` method ?

Comment: You already got the solution from yawnston or David Pilkington. But you should read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth) that gives you a much better understanding of async/await.

Comment: Be careful with thread-safety inside the `UploadReportData` method. Each awaited `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` will cause a thread switch (unless all tasks are completed), meaning that the mutable `tasks` list is shared among threads. Although the usage pattern is not concurrent, there is still the theoretical possibility that a thread will see cached stale values of the internal state of the list. I would prefer not to risk it, and I would use a `lock`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use async/await, until the first await, all code in the method up to that point will run synchronously on the calling thread. If you want uploadToTable to be able to execute in parallel, you could use

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => uploadtoTable(item)));
```

Then they *might* run in parallel. A sidenote is that as a consequence of code being synchronous until the first await, having an async method with no awaits doesn't really make sense.

Comment: "having an async method with no awaits doesn't really make sense." No, both the methods has `awaits`

Comment: I mentioned an async method without awaits not making sense to illustrate the point that all code in an async method up to the first await will run synchronously. Not as a comment referring to your code.

Answer (score 1):

`async` `await` does not mean that the the task will be run on a new thread. It just means that it will not block if the operation has not completed. `WhenAll` simply aggregates this into another `Task`, which follows the same pattern.

The `TaskScheduler` will then decide how those tasks are run, the could be run synchronously on the same thread if it thinks that is best.

You can try a `Parallel.ForEach` if you want it to run in parallel but note that this will block the calling thread.